# How to restore nuget private feed using MSBuild in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core, msbuild, nuget

I'm configuring an existing project (dotnet core) to use private nuget repository.
I've setup my project with the structure as follows:

- Project1
- Project2
- Project3
- .sln
- nuget.config

I'm able to restore my packages if i'm to run a "dotnet restore" commands but not while using Visual Studio's build (MSBuild).

***I would like to be able to restore my package while using Visual Studio's MSBuild.(not using cli)***

If possible, i'd like to avoid using msbuild's Exec task to run dotnet restore before build.

- I've tried them in both Visual Studio 2017 and 2019

Comment: If you're using msbuild (15.x and 16.x versions), you can use the restore switch when you call the command. The path of the msbuild.exe will always to be: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\xxx\MSBuild\15.0\Bin` or `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin`.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to run the MSBuild `Restore` target before the actual target. MSBuild.exe provides a built-in way to execute this target, then flush all caches (needed to avoid incremental build issues due to freshly restored packages) and then perform the actual build with the the `-r` (long: `-restore`) argument:

e.g.:

```
msbuild -r -p:Configuration=Release the.sln
```